# jQuery: If-condition within external plugin call options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery `$.each` function to call a certain datepicker plugin on multiple text inputs at once. Some text inputs, however, need to be called using a certain "minDate" option.

Now, here's the basic plugin call:

```
    new Pikaday({ 
        field: document.getElementById(identification),
    });
```

Now, instead of doing this:

```
if (condition === true) {
    new Pikaday({ 
        field: document.getElementById(identification),
        minDate: new Date(moment().format("YYYY, MM, DD"))

    });
} else {
    new Pikaday({ 
        field: document.getElementById(identification),
    });
}
```

I would like to know how I include the "minDate" option for only the elements that apply to my if-condition in a more optimised way. This might be a very basic question, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around this yet. Any ideas?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: What is your if-condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for this

```
new Pikaday({ 
    field: document.getElementById(identification),
    minDate: condition === true ? new Date(moment().format("YYYY, MM, DD")) : undefined
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this worked for me! Will accept the answer asap.